# Deserialising json string to List<T>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a web service that is outputting JSON in the form

```
{"AppointmentList":[{"AppointmentList":{"id":"1","MeetingId":"1","MeetingName":"Test Meeting 1","Length":"90","Room":"B2C","DateTimeFrom":"1st Sept 2016","Venue":"The old pub","DateCreated":"2016-08-30 00:00:00","DateDue":"2016-09-01 00:00:00","UserId":"JohnsonPa"}},{"AppointmentList":{"id":"2","MeetingId":"2","MeetingName":"Test Meeting 2","Length":"60","Room":"B2C","DateTimeFrom":"11th Sept 2016","Venue":"The old pub","DateCreated":"2016-09-01 00:00:00","DateDue":"2016-09-12 00:00:00","UserId":"JohnsonPa"}...}]}
```

I am trying to deserialise this in to List. Normally, I would have a Base Class that would contain a property List AppointmentList {get; set;}, however, that would mean that I can't use type T and need a pile of duplicate code for each class.

I can certainly create BaseClass with a property public List Data {get; set;} however, as the JSON won't deserialise to Data (incorrect name) and the JSON PropertyName can't be set to the class name derived from typeof(T).ToString().

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do without resorting to lots of code duplication?

I've tried casting the deserialiser to JArray and creating a reader from that, but this throws an exception.

Comment: Not sure why having a concrete class for this object will prevent you using generics? And really, it would be best to create a view model that matches the object for deserialzing

Comment: Why would I want a view model for this - it's purely data so can be handled within a model.

Comment: Just terminology - call it a DTO if you prefer. Point being, in order to deserialize it it's perhaps better to tell whatever mechanism you're using what Type to deserialize to. Especially if you're passing this object around. Still doesn't answer why this would affect using generics

Comment: Why do you want to deserialize AppointmentList to a property called Data? Why can't it be called AppointmentList?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is exactly what you need, but maybe something like this would work? It allows you to successfully deserialize to a JArray like you state you tried at the end of your question.

```
JArray result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json).AppointmentList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how to convert it to `List<object>`

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
JArray array = data.AppointmentList;

List<object> objectList = array.ToObject<List<object>>();
```

Comment: Thanks. Only issue is that I pass in T which is the class, therefore data.T won't give anything.

Comment: @Nodoid If I understand you correctly write the className instead of object. Or you have this json in some generic class and you want to return List<T> from this generic method. In this case if the T:object, it should not be a problem to write List<T> ?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with generics? If you want a schemaless data structure use JObject or dynamic if not you can try this.

```
 class Program
    {
        public const string json = @"{""AppointmentList"":[{""AppointmentList"":{""id"":""1"",""MeetingId"":""1"",""MeetingName"":""Test Meeting 1"",""Length"":""90"",""Room"":""B2C"",""DateTimeFrom"":""1st Sept 2016"",""Venue"":""The old pub"",""DateCreated"":""2016-08-30 00:00:00"",""DateDue"":""2016-09-01 00:00:00"",""UserId"":""JohnsonPa""}},{""AppointmentList"":{""id"":""2"",""MeetingId"":""2"",""MeetingName"":""Test Meeting 2"",""Length"":""60"",""Room"":""B2C"",""DateTimeFrom"":""11th Sept 2016"",""Venue"":""The old pub"",""DateCreated"":""2016-09-01 00:00:00"",""DateDue"":""2016-09-12 00:00:00"",""UserId"":""JohnsonPa""}}]}";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppointmentItemList<Meeting1>>(json).GetList();

            var items2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppointmentItemList<Meeting2>>(json).GetList();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class AppointmentItemList<T> 
        {
            public List<AppointmentItem> AppointmentList { get; set; }

            public class AppointmentItem 
            {
                public T AppointmentList { get; set; }
            }

            public IList<T> GetList()
            {
                return AppointmentList.Select(al => al.AppointmentList).ToList();
            }
        }

        public class Meeting1 
        {
            [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            public string MeetingName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Meeting2
        {
            [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            public string Room { get; set; }
        }
    }
```